# SlickGrid + jQuery Dialog Edit Form

Tags: jquery, slickgrid, jquery-dialog

I have a SlickGrid `onClick` event wired up to open a jQuery dialog so that certain fields and values from my dataView populated the dialog box when the user clicks a certain cell. Everything works fine, but I am having a hard time saving the form data back to the grid. I was following this [example](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/gh-pages/examples/example-composite-editor-item-details.html), but I am using a dataView so I'm not sure if there are some changes I have to make. this portion of the code fires, but the when the dialog box closes the dataView is not updated with the forms data. Is there a piece of code I am missing? Thanks

```
$modal.find("[data-action=save]").click(function () {
    grid.getEditController().commitCurrentEdit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the proper way of doing it, but this is what I was able to work out using my limited jQuery knowledge and the [Wiki for Data Views](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/DataView)

```
// find the button on the jQuery dialog and use this click event
 $('.ui-dialog-buttonset').find("[data-action=save]").on('click', function () {

    //these are the IDs for the inputs on my dialog
    var startDate = $('#dialog-StartDate').val();
    var dueDate = $('#dialog-DueDate').val();
    var lbsForJob = $('#dialog-LbsForJob').val();

    //I have a data attribute on my save buton that has the unique ID
    var dialogId = $('#editRowDialogSave').data('id');

    // per the wiki for data views, update the data view row
    var item = dataView.getItemById(dialogId);
    item['LbsNeededForJob'] = lbsForJob;
    item['StartDate'] = startDate;
    item['DueDate'] = dueDate;
    dataView.updateItem(dialogId, item);

});
```